# Ошибка в классе Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

У меня есть такой код:

```
class Auto:
    name = 'Mercedes'
    old = 2015
    speed = 230
    color = 'Black'
    price = 3000000
    
    def __init__(self, name, old, speed, color, price):
            self.name = name
            self.old = old
            self.speed = speed
            self.color = color
            self.price = price

    def search(self):
            i = input('Введите название авто: ')
            if i == 'Mercedes':
                    print('Инфо об авто!', self.name, self.old, self.speed, self.color, self.price)
```

Но при запуске выдаёт ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\test.py", line 19, in 
> p = Auto()
> TypeError: **init**() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'name', 'old', 'speed', and 'color'

Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

или так:

```
class Auto:
    name = 'Mercedes'
    old = 2015
    speed = 230
    color = 'Black'
    price = 3000000
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def search(self):
        i = input('Введите название авто: ')
        if i == 'Mercedes':
            print('Инфо об авто!', 
                  self.name, 
                  self.old, 
                  self.speed, 
                  self.color, 
                  self.price
                 )
                    

auto = Auto()
auto.search()
```

или так:

```
class Auto:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.name = 'Mercedes'
        self.old = 2015
        self.speed = 230
        self.color = 'Black'
        self.price = 3000000

    def search(self):
        i = input('Введите название авто: ')
        if i == 'Mercedes':
            print('Инфо об авто!', 
                  self.name, 
                  self.old, 
                  self.speed, 
                  self.color, 
                  self.price
                 )
                    

auto = Auto()
auto.search()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё так можно - класс содержит словарь экземпляров-автомобилей:

```
class Auto:
    autos = dict()

    def __init__(self, name, old, speed, color, price):
        self.name = name
        self.old = old
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color
        self.price = price
        Auto.autos[self.name] = self

    def search():
        i = input('Введите название авто: ')
        if i in Auto.autos:
            auto = Auto.autos[i]
            print('Инфо об авто!', auto.name, auto.old, auto.speed, auto.color, auto.price)
        else:
            print('Авто не найдено!', i)

Auto(name = 'Lada', old = 1990, speed = 100, color = 'White', price = 300000)
Auto(name = 'Mercedes', old = 2015, speed = 230, color = 'Black', price = 3000000)
Auto(name = 'Porsche', old = 2015, speed = 330, color = 'Red', price = 30000000)

Auto.search()
Auto.search()
```

Ввод-вывод:

```
Введите название авто: Mercedes
Инфо об авто! Mercedes 2015 230 Black 3000000
Введите название авто: Geely
Авто не найдено! Geely
```